# How do I change my Deepin terminal text/command colour from greeen to white?

Tags: bash, debian, terminal, zsh, deepin

I've tried every SO and regular article with instructions on changing the text/foreground colour of my terminal, but nothing works. I have a VM with Debian-based Linux Deepin and I have installed ZShell. But no matter zshell or bash, the text always stays signal green. I really would like to make it white. On my pycharm the terminal there shows white and I see a different icon at the beginning of the line, which is not the Linux icon I see in the regular terminal, so I think that one has a different terminal (forgive me, I don't know much about it yet).

In my terminal I thought something is overriding the colors, I tried setting colours manually as well as enable the **force_color_prompt** and also tried setting up different options for **PS1**, **nothing works**. This happens in both zsh and bash shells.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6y8V.png) is a photo in both zsh and bash.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Deepin terminal, but [a quick DuckDuckGo search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=deepin+terminal+settings) reveals that in Deepin terminal's main menu, you can [switch the theme](https://wiki.deepin.org/index.php?title=Deepin_Terminal&language=en#Switch_Theme) and also [change the font](https://wiki.deepin.org/index.php?title=Deepin_Terminal&language=en#Basic_Settings).

Your PyCharm terminal is displaying the exact same Linux icon as your Deepin terminal, but for some reason, the icon is getting clipped on the right. You might want to file a bug report about that with JetBrains, the company that makes PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the icon - it's coming from the Zsh theme, not pycharm, so no need to contact JetBrains. The issue is about the colour of the text/commands in the terminal. I did check the original terminal's theme, but there really isn't anything addressing this problem. That's the first place I checked and then started digging into dotfiles. Couldn't find anything there too and no SO answer helped as well so I asked here

Comment: "it's coming from the Zsh theme, not pycharm, so no need to contact JetBrains": It's the exact same icon, which apparently you have in an icon font, but PyCharm is not rendering it correctly. It's cutting off the right edge of it. So, yes, the problem is in PyCharm.

Comment: The default color of the text/commands in the terminal is coming from your terminal. That's why it's different in PyCharm: It uses a different terminal, with a different default text color. Either you have to find the right setting to change it in Deepin Terminal or you just have to use another terminal.